# Applying a transformation over a given set

Tags: linear-transformations

While i was reading through my calculus recitations, i stumbled upon this example: suppose we have $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: 0 \leq y,0 \leq x\leq 9, 1 \leq x^2-y^2 \leq 9\}$. 
$U=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 0<x<y\}$

$V=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : 0<x, 0<y\}$

let $T:U\rightarrow V$ and $S:V\rightarrow U$ two transformations, defined as:
\begin{equation} T \begin{pmatrix} x \\\ y \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{y} \\\ \sqrt{y-x} \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} S \begin{pmatrix} x \\\ y \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} x^2 - y^2 \\\ x^2  \end{pmatrix} \end{equation}

we can see that $S=T^{-1}$.

so in the recitations they calculated the set $T^{-1}(D)$ as the following: 
$T^{-1}$$ (D)= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: 0 \leq \sqrt{y-x},0 \leq \sqrt{y} \leq 9, 1 \leq \sqrt{y^2}-\sqrt{(y-x)^2} \leq 9\}$

I'm struggling to understand why this is the right set, i see that we applied the transformation $T$ over the endpoints of the intervals of D instead of applying $T^{-1}=S$

Comment: $T$ and $S$ are not linear